# How to include boost header only library in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I'm trying to include a boost header only library, specifically, `<boost/variant>`, using a Qt Creator project.

This is what I have added to my `.pro` file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/boost \
```

Now, if I go into a `.cpp` file and try including..

```
#include <variant.hpp>
```

works, but

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
```

does not.

This makes sense, since I'm adding `/usr/include/boost/`, not `/usr/include`.
However, if I instead do

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include
```

I get a ton of cmath related errors, which seem to be related to adding `/usr/include` to the include path - https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/452

If I just do `#include <variant.hpp>` in my code, then the boost code complains - `'boost/variant/variant.hpp' file not found`.

How do I correctly allow `<boost/variant.hpp>` style imports to work without including the whole of `/usr/include/`?

Minimal example code:

```
# Example.pro
QT += quick
CONFIG += c++17

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include <boost/variant.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

`qml.qrc`

```xml
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

```
// main.qml
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

ApplicationWindow {
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] ?

Comment: @selbie I have attempted to add a minimal example - It doesn't lend very well to being ran, since I'm compiling for android - You need a ton of dependencies to get started.

Comment: Seem my updated answer. I'm suggesting you could use a symlink to workaround this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement:

```
#include <variant>
```

Is pulling in the std C++ header file for variant, and gives your code access to [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), not the Boost version.

This statement:

```
#include <boost/variant>
```

Will likely not compile - because `/usr/include/boost/variant` is a directory itself, not a file that can be included.

If you want the Boost version of the `variant` header, I think you want this in your .cpp file:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
```

And you shouldn't have to mess with your `INCLUDEPATH` assuming the `/usr/include/boost` folder exists.

**Update**
Assuming /usr/include is the source of conflicting header files, one thing you could try is doing a symlink to boost from a different folder.

```
cd                              # cd to home directory
mkdir include                   # create a local "include" folder
cd include                      # cd to this folder
ln -s /usr/include/boost boost  # create a symlink to boost
```

Then update your include path to point to this directory

```
INCLUDEPATH += /home/yourname/include
```

Where `/home/yourname` is your home directory.

That will allow you to pull in `<boost/variant.hpp>` without potential conflicts elsewhere in `/usr/include`

Comment: Apologies, I checked my code again, and I am in fact doing `#include <boost/variant.hpp>`. Good point on the `<variant>` including `std::variant` - I forgot about that.

Comment: Using a sym link works perfectly - Thanks! However, obviously this makes it difficult for other developers to build the code. Is including `/usr/include` fine, and I just need to find a way to get it playing nice on android?

Comment: Getting Qt installed and building anything correctly is 10x harder than this issue!  You could just include Boost in your git repo (perhaps a git submodule) and have your build environment set a relative path to that folder.  Not sure what the equivalent of nuget or cocoapods on linux is, but you want to be going the route of users pulling down boost headers from the build environment.

Comment: That's a good idea. I was initially following that path, as I'm only using variant, which is header only. Annoyingly, they kept recursively requiring more libraries. I'll probably take another shot at getting just what I need locally. Thanks again.